# angular material tags render as html tags

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Currently I have requirement where I need to convert HTML to PDF , since I'm using angular material inputs to render UI, angular material tags are not recognized by the PDF converter tools.

Need to know if there is any way or some setting within framework where it will render the angular material tags as HTML in browser?

below is HTML which renders angular material

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <md-content class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="center start" layout-xs="column">
        <div flex="50" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100" layout="column">
          <md-card>
            <md-card-title>
              <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">Card with image</span>
                <span class="md-subhead">Large</span>
              </md-card-title-text>
              <md-card-title-media>
                <div class="md-media-lg card-media"></div>
              </md-card-title-media>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
              <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
              <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
            </md-card-actions>
          </md-card>      
        </div>    
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to compile your code first using `$compile`, inside a directive ?

Comment: Actually rendering in browser is not having any issue, it renders as expected . But it renders with angular material tags like <md-content> which PDF conversion tool dosent understand.